# Getting invalid_payment response from uber with 400 status code;using rest API

Tags: uber-api

I am using REST API to book and uber ride using: https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests .
It's not working with payment methods other than Cash. 
I am getting 400 with code:invalid_payment
Can someone please help me out;

1. I am able to make payment using cash & Paytm for Indian locations.
2. I am not able to make payment using cash for US locations.
3. I am not able to make payment using the card for Indian & US locations.
4. When I add a new card via the Uber app and try to book a cab in the uber using the card it works; When I try to use the same card using my app it shows error. After this when I try to book a cab using the uber app; it doesn't work.

This the the response I am getting from Uber:

```
{
  "data": {
    "meta": {},
    "errors": [
      {
        "status": 400,
        "code": "invalid_payment",
        "title": "The rider's payment method is invalid and they must update their billing info."
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400,
  "headers": {
    "server": "nginx",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=604800",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "content-geo-system": "wgs-84",
    "date": "Fri, 05 Apr 2019 06:28:50 GMT",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "content-length": "151",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
  },
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 180000,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, /*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "authorization": "Bearer JA.ZWU",
      "Accept-Language": "en_US"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests",
    "data": "{\"start_latitude\":40.8037381,\"start_longitude\":-73.9577813,\"end_latitude\":40.68780810000001,\"end_longitude\":-73.8057292,\"fare_id\":\"7636a3afa24d7648656aabbcc695bf094d4eed6d9323f3b10a5a5868a47c\",\"product_id\":\"b64-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186\",\"payment_method_id\":\"0xxxx-90ce-4c1d-a8c4-af7b1a00c3cf\"}"
  },
  "request": {
    "UNSENT": 0,
    "OPENED": 1,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
    "LOADING": 3,
    "DONE": 4,
    "readyState": 4,
    "status": 400,
    "timeout": 180000,
    "withCredentials": true,
    "upload": {},
    "_aborted": false,
    "_hasError": false,
    "_method": "POST",
    "_response": "{\"meta\":{},\"errors\":[{\"status\":400,\"code\":\"invalid_payment\",\"title\":\"The rider's payment method is invalid and they must update their billing info.\"}]}",
    "_url": "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests",
    "_timedOut": false,
    "_trackingName": "unknown",
    "_incrementalEvents": false,
    "responseHeaders": {
      "Server": "nginx",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=604800",
      "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Geo-System": "wgs-84",
      "Date": "Fri, 05 Apr 2019 06:28:50 GMT",
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
      "Content-Length": "151",
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block"
    },
    "_requestId": null,
    "_headers": {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, /*",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "authorization": "Bearer JA.VUNU",
      "accept-language": "en_US"
    },
    "_responseType": "",
    "_sent": true,
    "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {
      "server": "nginx",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=604800",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "content-geo-system": "wgs-84",
      "date": "Fri, 05 Apr 2019 06:28:50 GMT",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "content-length": "151",
      "cache-control": "max-age=0",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
    },
    "_subscriptions": [],
    "responseURL": "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests"
  }
}
```

Actual result should be ride request accepted.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. What is your client ID and can you also link to your IOS store / google play store link for your app?

Comment: @KyleDavis The app is not live yet. Client_id: _zbncz42y6SFkzoutBNodWyZxwgwIB7O

Comment: @KyleDavis Could you please tell me why our cards(debit & credit both) are being blocked?

Comment: Your individual issue with a payment method is unrelated to the API. I do not know why you are flagged, perhaps there was detection of fraudulent activity. You can follow up directly with uber support on that through the uber app or at help.uber.com. In terms of the request scope- that would not be granted here so it is not relevant moving forward. Hope that helps wrap this up. Thank you.

Comment: @KyleDavis Is credit card payment option available when I use deep links?

Comment: Deeplinks lead into the Uber app, where a user can pay with a credit card, yes.

Comment: I tried a couple of accounts and with every account, I get the same error. Have a look at the screenshot: http://172.245.208.10/Screenshot_2019-04-19-17-33-58-723_com.flewber.png  You can see the message for card

Comment: @KyleDavis Does it seem deeplink doesn't support card?

Comment: If you can't just take an Uber ride with your payment method through the Uber app, that confirms this is not an API issue and you should follow up directly with Uber support through help.uber.com or the Uber app. Specifically try and take a ride through the Uber app. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleDavis Have you seen the image I sent? This card is working with Uber app. with deeplinks it shows an error. Please read comments before replying. This is not helping me at all.

Comment: I did read your message & look at the image. Your image is not the Uber app is it? It looks like mobile web. Deeplinks = into the Uber app. Universal links = into the uber app or mobile web. As a guess, it looks like Uber have the credit card turned off on mobile web possibly for fraud reasons for your account or geo. That isn't an API issue or technical issue but looks like a specific Uber decision they made.

Comment: Hi Kyle. I have started receiving this error while using deep links https://imgur.com/a/y5sTnUB . I receive this error when after I enter my Uber credentials